# How to binarize pictures faster

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmap

I'm currently trying to binarize the image, the following is the code I used:

```
private static Bitmap PBinary(Bitmap src, int v)
{
    int w = src.Width;
    int h = src.Height;

    Bitmap dstBitmap = new Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData srcData = src.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData dstData = dstBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    unsafe
    {
        byte* pIn = (byte*)srcData.Scan0.ToPointer();
        byte* pOut = (byte*)dstData.Scan0.ToPointer();
        byte* p;
        int stride = srcData.Stride;
        int r, g, b;
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
            {
                p = pIn;
                r = p[2];
                g = p[1];
                b = p[0];
                pOut[0] = pOut[1] = pOut[2] = (byte)(((byte)(0.2125 * r + 0.7154 * g + 0.0721 * b) >= v) ? 255 : 0);
                pIn += 3;
                pOut += 3;
            }
            pIn += srcData.Stride - w * 3;
            pOut += srcData.Stride - w * 3;
        }
        src.UnlockBits(srcData);
        dstBitmap.UnlockBits(dstData);
        return dstBitmap;
    }
}
```

I can successfully binarize the picture, but when I add a slider to dynamically adjust the parameters, I find that the picture is very stuck when displayed.

```
    private void BinarySlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        if (originalImg!=null)
        {
            BinaryPara = (int)e.NewValue;

            PreviewImg = PBinary(originalImg, BinaryPara);

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                img.Source = null;

                img.Source = BitmapToBitmapSource(PreviewImg);

            });

        }

    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    public static BitmapSource BitmapToBitmapSource(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

        BitmapSource retval;

        try
        {
            retval = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                         hBitmap,
                         IntPtr.Zero,
                         Int32Rect.Empty,
                         BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        finally
        {
            DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        }

        return retval;

    }
```

I tried to use opencvsharp again, and found that using opencvsharp to dynamically adjust the parameters of the binarization, the picture was displayed very smoothly without any freezes.

But currently I don’t want to use third-party libraries. Is there any way to binarize images faster?

thank you all!

Comment: I'd calculate the greyscale matrix *once* after the image is loaded in a 2D integer (to avoid slower floating-point calculation) array, and only run the comparison against the v repeatedly. If the image is particularly larger than the control displaying it, it might even worth it to run the process against a resized version for preview, only process the full image once user save the result.

Comment: @Martheen Thank you very much for your reply. I'm not sure about the impact of floating-point calculation, but I don't think it's the main problem about the actual size of the image and the display control, because when using opencvsharp, I didn't adjust the image size, but the image can still be displayed smoothly.

Comment: opencv are obviously way faster than managed code implementation, unless you want to rewrite every little gritty memory operation, try precalculating the matrix. Floating point calculation is *very* expensive compared to integer, and with precalculation you take out nearly all the CPU time.

Comment: @Martheen The biggest problem is that I don't know how to write grayscale matrix. Can you provide some reference code? thank you very much!

Comment: At your very end of your comparison, you do  `>= v) ? 255 : 0`, take this out, you get the double value, cast it to integer, done, that's it, there's your grayscale matrix as a bitmap.

Comment: Floating point calculations are usually not an issue nowadays. Try to avoid the WinForms Bitmap class and its probably expensive conversion to BitmapSource. Use a single WriteableBitmap instead.

Comment: You may also create a FormatConvertedBitmap first from the original bitmap, with a DestinationFormat of e.g. `PixelFormats.Gray8` to create an initial grayscale bitmap.

Comment: @Martheen Thank you for your help. I tried your method, but it didn't seem to be faster. When I drag the slider, the image display will still be stuck.

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: Even faster then WriteableBitmap might be a BitmapSource with a 256 color palette. Instead of modifying the pixel buffer, you would simply adjust the colors in the palette.

Comment: @Clemens  Thank you for your reply. If I use the "FormatConvertedBitmap" method, the threshold will be missing and the parameters cannot be adjusted dynamically. In addition, I tested the WriteableBitmap method, which is much slower than my original method. I don't know why.

Comment: @Martheen I take the part you mentioned our and compare it after calculation. The code is as follows:                        d = 0.2125 * r + 0.7154 * g + 0.0721 * b;

                        if ((int)d >= v)
                        {
                            pOut[0] = pOut[1] = pOut[2] = 255;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pOut[0] = pOut[1] = pOut[2] = 0;
                        }

Comment: Edit your question. You don't show whether you actually keep that matrix and only compare it against v when needed.

Comment: @Martheen Thank you very much for your patience to answer my questions, but I really don't understand what the "matrix" you said is, and I don't know how to create this "matrix".

Comment: matrix is 2D arrays. The goal is instead of reading the image and get the greyscale values *everytime* user move the slider, it's only done *once*, stored as its own variable. Then when user move the slider, it's a simple for inside for inside the matrix to generate the binarized image.

Comment: @Martheen I'm very sorry, I can understand your idea, but I really don't know how to write this code.

Comment: When did it start to get choppy for you? I tried optimizing a bit and it still got choppy at 4K, smooth at HD resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be *exactly* what you need, but it should give you a basic idea of how to create different binarized bitmaps from the same, unmodified raw pixel buffer.

In a first step, it creates a 8-bits-per-pixel grayscale BitmapSource from the original BitmapSource, and copies its buffer to a byte array. Each byte in the buffer is a gray value in the range 0 to 255. The trick is to reuse this as an index into a color palette with 256 entries.

Now each time the threshold value (i.e. the Value of a Slider with range 0 to 255) changes, a color palette with 256 entries is created, but it only contains `Black` for indices below the threshold, and `White`for indices above.

```
private int pixelWidth;
private int pixelHeight;
private byte[] pixelBuffer;

public MainWindow()
{
    var source = new BitmapImage(...);

    // create grayscale bitmap from original

    var grayscale = new FormatConvertedBitmap(
        source, PixelFormats.Gray8, null, 0d);

    pixelWidth = grayscale.PixelWidth;
    pixelHeight = grayscale.PixelHeight;
    pixelBuffer = new byte[pixelWidth * pixelHeight];

    // get raw pixel buffer

    grayscale.CopyPixels(pixelBuffer, pixelWidth, 0);

    InitializeComponent();
}

private void UpdateImage(byte threshold)
{
    var colors = new Color[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < threshold; i++)
    {
        colors[i] = Colors.Black;
    }

    for (int i = threshold; i < 256; i++)
    {
        colors[i] = Colors.White;
    }

    // set the Source of an Image element declared in XAML
    // pixelBuffer is now used as an array of indices into a color palette

    image.Source = BitmapSource.Create(
        pixelWidth, pixelHeight, 96, 96,
        PixelFormats.Indexed8, new BitmapPalette(colors),
        pixelBuffer, pixelWidth);
}

private void Slider_ValueChanged(
    object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    UpdateImage((byte)e.NewValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. According to your code, the modified picture can indeed be displayed very smoothly. This is a very good idea. If my original code does not have a better optimization solution, I will use your method To realize my function, thanks!

Comment: You may probably also want to take a look at PixelShaders: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.effects.shadereffect?view=net-5.0